# Call a method inside of class to save Object in a dictionary

Tags: python

I have a class like below:

```
class User:
    def __init__(self, phone_number):
        self.phone_number = phone_number
        self.name = 'john'
        self.role = 'normal'
        

    def cache_it(self):
        # save object to dict, use phone_number as key and whole object as value
```

And I have a dictionary named `users_cache`. I want to use this class like below:

```
user1 = User('+123456789')
user1.cache_it()
```

And when I use `users_cache['+123456789']` get the cached User (Object).

Comment: What problem are you having? It's just a simple assignment to a dictionary element.

Comment: What exactly is the problem you ran in to?

Comment: How can I point to the whole Object as a value?

Comment: Why have you tagged contradictory versions of Python?

Comment: The variable `self` is the whole object.

Comment: The same way you refer to *any object*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variable `self` is the whole object and it can be used as a value to save in a dictionary or any where else like below:

```
def cache_it(self):
    users_cache[self.phone_number] = self
```

Now we can cache an object to our dictionary (`users_cache`) like below:

```
user1 = User('+123456789')
user1.cache_it()
```

And getting back the object like this:

```
load_from_cache = users_cache['+123456789']
```

Comment: `users_cache` then has to be a `global`, which is undesirable. What about passing it in as an argument to `cache_it`? i.e. `def cache_it(self, cache):`

Answer (score 0):

Caching shouldn't really be the responsibility of the `User` class.

Implement it externally:

```
users_cache = {}

user1 = User('+123456789')

users_cache[user1.phone_number] = user1
```